# ProtoBuf - Can a field support two possible datatypes?

Tags: nestjs, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-node, protobuf.js

is it possible for one field in protobuf to support/accept a string or an array of string.
This is my message:

```
message MessageA {
  string fieldId =1;
  string method = 2;
  google.protobuf.Any value =3;
}
```

The reason for it being dynamic is because an array of string or a simple string can be the input. There are separate methods on what will happen if the payload is string[] or string.

Right now, I'm using `any` but I'm not sure what to do in the `any` file. I've read that `oneof` does not support array data types thats why I'm trying to make it work with `any`.

Here is the error message when I try to put a `repeated` inside a `oneof`:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might have the same problem as me, you can use `google.protobuf.Value`. There would be an additional object but it can be transformed using UsePipe so it shouldn't be a problem.

Here is the documentation: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Value

Answer (score 0):

No, basically. The main way of doing this would be to have two inner-types - one with a single-valued member, one with a `repeated` member, and have a `oneof` that covers the two inner-types. Or perhaps simpler: just have a `repeated` and *separately* have an enum, boolean, or other indicator to choose between the two possible meanings (so you can tell between "an array, that happened to have exactly one item" vs "the single value").

Comment: Hello, I tried your first proposal: create a `oneof` that has a repeated member and a single valued member. I'm getting an error because `repeated` is not supported in `oneof`.

Comment: @astra-xvi you need to wrap the `repeated` field in a `message` and use the `message` as a `oneof` alternative.

Comment: @astra.xvi as DazWilkin says: I was advocating creating two message types, each with the required setup, and oneof *those*